# Linq to SQL self join where right part of join is filtered

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am trying to map a self join where the right table must be filtered, e.g.  SQL such as this:

```
select t2.* from table t 
    left join table t2 
    on t2.parentID = t.ID and t2.active=1;
```

I can figure out the syntax if I wanted to filter the *left* table:

```
// works
var query = from t in table
               where t.active= 1
            join t2 in table
               on t.parentID equals t2.ID into joined
            from r in joined.DefaultIfEmpty() ...
```

But I can't figure out how to filter the right table. It seems like it should be something like this...

```
// does not work
var query = from t in table
            join t2 in table
               where t.field = 1
               on t.parentID equals t2.ID into joined
            from r in joined.DefaultIfEmpty() ...
```

(not valid... `join` can't have where). There is discussion of using multiple from clauses, but if I create more than one from clause, so I can add a `where` to the 2nd one, I can't figure out how to join the results of them into a new temporary table.

I can't just add a "where" after the join; the right table must be filtered first or matches will occur, and a `where` clause at the end would remove the row from the left table that I do want in the output. That is, the output should have rows where there's nothing matched from filtered right table. So I need to filter the right table before the join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking to do this:

```
var query = from t in table
            join t2 in 
               (from t3 in table
                where t3.field = 1
                select t3)
               on t.parentID equals t2.ID into joined
            from r in joined.DefaultIfEmpty() ...
```

Another way is to use multiple `from` like this:

```
var query = from t in table
            from t2 in table.Where(x => x.field = 1)
                            .Where(x => x.ID == t.parentID)
                            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            select ....
```

Comment: Ah, I just wasn't thinking of this as a subquery! Perfect, thanks.